# PHP - drop only one table from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-drop

I've searched a long time and didn't found correct answer for this question that i want to delete only one table from database. so i have this:

```
<?php

$database_name = "XXXXXX";

if (!$link = mysql_connect('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX')) {
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $database_name";
if($result = mysql_query($sql)){

  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $found_tables[]=$row[0];
  }
}
else{
  die("Error, could not list tables. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
}

 foreach($found_tables as $table_name){
  $sql = "DROP TABLE $database_name.$table_name";
  if($result = mysql_query($sql)){
    echo "Success - table $table_name deleted.";
  }
  else{
    echo "Error deleting $table_name. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error() . "";
  }
}
?>
```

it will list all tables from database and delete all of theme but i want to delete them one by one. something like this:

> delete.php?item=ONE_OF_TABLE

drop table by querystring with table name or ...

Comment: then do you need show tables or a loop? do you know the table names you want to drop?

Comment: no i don't know table names, they are dynamic. i exactly want to list up all tables by name and then delete them one by one. @Dagon

Comment: you say only one, and all of them, which is it?

Comment: `if ($_GET['item'] == 'table_name') DROP`

Comment: that codes are posted will delete all tables. but i don't want this. i want delete each table separately. delete one by one. @Dagon

Comment: i found random code on internet that does *not* do what i actully want, let me post it here, so you can completely change it to do what i actully want -um ok good luck with that

Answer (score 1):

First take a look on [mysql function deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Then your SQL-Syntax has to be edited by a `WHERE table_name LIKE 'ONE_OF_TABLE'`

or replace ONE_OF_TABLE by $_GET['item']

Answer (score 0):

The code posted does exactly what you want - it drops tables one by one in a cycle. If you mean - "Show tables to end user, THAN drop them one by one" - you should print the result of SHOW TABLES query and expect some other user interaction.